# JxMaps Null Pointer Exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, jxmaps

this is my first run for JxMaps lib
and i got a Null Pointer Exception in the first line 
-> final MapView mapView = new MapView();
this code is from JxMaps JavaFX Quick Start Guide
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb8rt.png)

Comment: Without the full stack trace it is almost impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem already fixed in the latest version of JxMaps. Please download new version from https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps.